# How to see what parameters a function or method can take in Python while working in Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: python-3.x, function, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, seaborn

While working with the *Seaborn* library I can use `?sns.barplot` (for example) to see what parameters this function takes. But when I am trying do the same for Python functions it doesn't work. Is there a way that I can get the same kind of information for functions while working on it, to save time and stay focused on the problem more than looking for how the function works.

Comment: Can you give an example of function for which it doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

You can use pythons built in [help()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#help) function to show documentation:

> Invoke the built-in help system. (This function is intended for interactive use.) If no argument is given, the interactive help system starts on the interpreter console. If the argument is a string, then the string is looked up as the name of a module, function, class, method, keyword, or documentation topic, and a help page is printed on the console. If the argument is any other kind of object, a help page on the object is generated.

Example:

```
import requests

help(dict.items)
help(requests.post)
```

Outputs:

```
items(...)
    D.items() -> a set-like object providing a view on D's items

Help on function post in module requests.api:

post(url, data=None, json=None, **kwargs)
    Sends a POST request.

    :param url: URL for the new :class:`Request` object.
    :param data: (optional) Dictionary, list of tuples, bytes, or file-like
        object to send in the body of the :class:`Request`.
    :param json: (optional) json data to send in the body of :class:`Request`.
    :param \*\*kwargs: Optional arguments that `request` takes.
    :return: :class:`Response <Response>` object
    :rtype: requests.Response
```

Comment: Mr. Patrick thanks for you time and effort you put into writting this comment. It is going to great help for me.